# How to send and receive text messages without MFMessageComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to send and receive text messages without showing  `MFMessageViewController` from my application. Could anybody tell me how is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Possible , Unless you use 3rd party api for send/received sms.

Comment: okay thank you , but can you tell me that how to do it using 3rd party api ?

Comment: @SantuC can nexmo be used to send user locations? Like a map pin?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use Web service and Apple Push Notification Service for send message to other user without using `MFMessageComposeViewController`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without MFMessageComposeViewController. Apple won't allow to send SMS without user interaction.

I've alternate solution of this, out of scope of iOS. Use web service API. Create a web service at server side that send a message to specific number(s) that accept numbers as parameters with request.

At specific time interval (according to your requirement) send a web service call with number as request parameter.

Web server can do it. It can send message to any device.